# How prove that $|y-x|\le \frac 1n$ implies $|f(y)-f(x)|\le \frac1n|f(1)|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a ring isomorphism. How prove that $|y-x|\le \frac 1n$ implies $|\phi(y)-\phi(x)|\le \frac1n|\phi(1)|$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$? (Continuity)

I prove that I show that for $x>0$, then we can write $|x|=x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} \iff $ $\phi(\sqrt{x})\phi(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: so we don't know if $\phi$ is continuous or not?

Comment: @dREaM It's that I try to prove. Only one detail block me, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @fleablood how would you show $\phi(y)=y\phi(1)$? I can only do it if $y$ is rational.

Comment: Yes, indeed y is rational

Comment: What is  $f(x)$?

Comment: Wait what, $x$ and $y$ are rational?

Comment: Oh ok, then it is trivial.

Comment: @dREaM Is it sufficient to show the continuity only with rationnal numbers?

Comment: $\phi(n/m) = \phi(n)/phi(m) = \phi(n*1)/\phi(m*1) = (n/m)\phi(1)$  so $|\phi(x) - \phi(y)| = |\phi(1)(x - y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer then $\phi(n)=\phi(n1)=n\phi(1)$.

From here, $\phi(1/n)=\frac{1}{n\phi(1)}$

and so $\phi(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{p}{q}\phi(1)$ when $p\in\mathbb Z,q\in\mathbb Z^ +$

So if $x$ is rational $\phi(x)=x\phi(1)$.

So if $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ we obtain $|\phi(y)-\phi(x)|= |y\phi(1)-x\phi(1)|=|\phi(1)||y-x|$. From here it is clear if $|y-x|\leq\frac{1}{n}$ then $|\phi(1)||y-x|\leq\phi(1)\frac{1}{n}$.